# NextJs Ugly Url when use url parameters

Tags: next.js

Trying to add some filters to my url with url parameters.

But it returns ugly url.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const current_path = router.asPath
    const { sef } = router.query
      const groups = pickedProductGroup.join(',')
      const concepts = pickedProductConcept.join(',')

      const query = { group: groups, concept: concepts, q: querySearch }
      const url = { pathname: `/category/${sef}`, query }
      const urlAs = { pathname: `/category/${sef}`, query }

      router.push(url, urlAs, { shallow: false });
  }, [pickedProductGroup, pickedProductConcept, querySearch])
```

My expected url is like;
xxx.com/category/product?group=1,2&concept=3,5,6&q=blabla

but it returns like;
xxx.com/category/product?group=&concept=9%2C10%2C13%2C14&q=

Answer (score 0):

your href should be `/category/[product]` if that's the structure of your filesystem locally

As for cleaning up URLs, use `encodeURIComponent(url)` wrapper. That should help

If that doesn't help then use this filterQuery helper function:

```
export const filterQuery = (query: any) =>
    Object.keys(query).reduce<any>((obj, key) => {
        if (query[key]?.length) {
            obj[key] = query[key];
        }
        return obj;
    }, {});
```

here is an example of a searchbar component with the filterQuery function

```
import {
    FC,
    useEffect,
    useMemo,
    useState,
    useRef
} from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import css from '../Search/search.module.css';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Input } from '../../UI';
import { filterQuery } from '@/lib/helpers/filter-query';

// http://localhost:3030/repositories/advanced-ts-methods?q=advanced-ts-methods
export interface SearchbarProps {
    className?: string;
    id?: string;
}

const SearchUser: FC<SearchbarProps> = ({
    className,
    id = 'repos/'
}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const queryDynamic = useRef(router.query.login as string);
    useEffect(() => {
        // router.prefetch(url, as)
        router.prefetch(
            '/repos/[login]',
            `/repos/${router.query.login as string}`,
            {
                priority: true
            }
        );
    }, [value]);
    // memoize returned jsx for global state
    return useMemo(
        () => (
            <div
                className={cn(
                    'relative bg-accents-1 text-base w-full transition-colors duration-150',
                    className
                )}
            >
                <label className='sr-only' htmlFor={id}>
                    repo
                </label>
                <Input
                    id={id}
                    name={id}
                    onChange={setValue}
                    className={css.input}
                    placeholder='GitHub Username'
                    defaultValue={
                        router && router.query
                            ? (router.query.login as string)
                            : router.query
                            ? (router.query.q as string)
                            : ''
                    }
                    onKeyUp={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                            const login = e.currentTarget.value;

                            router.push(
                                {
                                    pathname: `/repos/${login}`,
                                    query: login ? filterQuery({ login }) : {}
                                },
                                undefined
                            );
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <div className={css.iconContainer}>
                    <svg
                        className={css.icon}
                        fill='rgb(229, 231, 235)'
                        viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                    >
                        <path
                            fillRule='evenodd'
                            clipRule='evenodd'
                            d='M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z'
                        />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        ),
        [queryDynamic.current]
    );
};

export default SearchUser;
```